# Why is asking question "time gap between a meal and sleep" -- considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, close-reasons, closed-questions, migration

Originally I had asked below question in [Fitness SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/posts/39304/revisions):
[What is the ideal time gap between lunch & power-nap as well as dinner & bedtime?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18103/what-is-the-ideal-time-gap-between-lunch-power-nap-as-well-as-dinner-bedtime)

Though I had a doubt, if it belonged to this SE. Later it was indeed migrated here. However it has been closed as off-topic:

> Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here

But, I don't see any wordings which is asking for any advise.

- Why is it off-topic & is there any way to reopen it by re-wording?
- Does it belong to any other SE site?

Answer (score 3):

It was closed because it asks for personal medical advice. The question is inherently personal and the answer will be different for everyone, so it's just not a good fit for this site. I don't see another site here that will fit the question.

Comment: To add to this - "Avoiding heartburn", that's different for everyone. What works for me might not work for you, etc. And on almost any SE site, asking for an "ideal" generally comes out to be too vague and/or broad.'